# Why does including fstream allow to access ofstream and ifstream?

Tags: c++, include, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

When i want to create objects of ifstream or ofstream, why its possible to include the header "fstream" without including Ifstream of Ofstream explicit.

thanx..

Comment: you are confusing header files with classes. don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard mandates that `<fstream>` has four *template-classes*, and eight types declared; among them are *std::fstream*, *std::ofstream*, and *std::ifstream*, as specified in section *27.9.1* in the Standard ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)).

---

It seems as if you are confusing the usage of *headers* with classes, but just because two or more names are available inside a certain header doesn't mean that the names introduced are related in terms of inheritance, or even usage.

Also; the name of a header doesn't always translate to the classes which are inside it. A header name is the name of a header (which has been chosen to summerize the contents of said header), nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Your observation has nothing to do with inheritance. The include file fstream itself includes ostream and istream.